# Multiprocessing proxy: let getters return proxies themselves

Tags: python, proxy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I have a complex unpickable object that has properties (defined via getters and setters) that are of complex and unpickable type as well. I want to create a multiprocessing proxy for the object to execute some tasks in parallel.

**The problem**: While I have succeeded to make the getter methods available for the proxy object, I fail to make the getters return proxies for the unpickable return objects.

My setup resembles the following:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy

class A():
    @property
    def a(self):
        return B()
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 2

# unpickable class
class B():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.f = lambda: 1
    

class ProxyBase(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__')

class AProxy(ProxyBase): pass
class BProxy(ProxyBase): pass
class MyManager(BaseManager):pass

MyManager.register('A', A, AProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyManager() as manager:
        myA = manager.A()
        print(myA.b) # works great
        print(myA.a) # raises error, because the object B is not pickable
```

I know that I can specify the result type of a method when registering it with the manager. That is, I can do

```
MyManager.register('A', A, AProxy, method_to_typeid={'__getattribute__':'B'})
MyManager.register('B', B, BProxy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyManager() as manager:
        myA = manager.A()
        print(myA.a) # works great!
        print(myA.b) # returns the same as myA.a ?!
```

It is clear to me that my solution does not work since the `__getattr__` method applies to all properties, whereas I only want it to return a proxy for `B` when property `a` is accessed. How could I achieve this?

As a side question: if I remove the `*args` argument from the  `__init__` method of `B`, I get an error that it is called with the wrong number of arguments. Why? How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't this is possible without some hacks, since the choice to return a value or proxy is made based on the method name alone, and not the type of the return value (from `Server.serve_client`):

```
try:
    res = function(*args, **kwds)
except Exception as e:
    msg = ('#ERROR', e)
else:
    typeid = gettypeid and gettypeid.get(methodname, None)
    if typeid:
        rident, rexposed = self.create(conn, typeid, res)
        token = Token(typeid, self.address, rident)
        msg = ('#PROXY', (rexposed, token))
    else:
        msg = ('#RETURN', res)
```

Also keep in mind exposing `__getattribute__` in an unpickable class's proxy basically breaks the proxy functionality when calling methods.

But if you're willing to hack it and just need attribute access, here is a working solution (note calling `myA.a.f()` still won't work, the lambda is an attribute and is not proxied, only methods are, but that's a different problem).

```
import os
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy, Server

class A():
    @property
    def a(self):
        return B()
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 2

# unpickable class
class B():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.f = lambda: 1
        self.pid = os.getpid()

class HackedObj:
    def __init__(self, obj, gettypeid):
        self.obj = obj
        self.gettypeid = gettypeid

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == '__getattribute__':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
            
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj')
        result = object.__getattribute__(obj, attr)
        if isinstance(result, B):
            gettypeid = object.__getattribute__(self, 'gettypeid')
            # This tells the server that the return value of this method is
            # B, for which we've registered a proxy.
            gettypeid['__getattribute__'] = 'B'


        return result

class HackedDict:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        obj, exposed, gettypeid = self.data[key]
        if isinstance(obj, A):
            gettypeid = gettypeid.copy() if gettypeid else {}
            # Now we need getattr to update gettypeid based on the result
            # luckily BaseManager queries the typeid info after the function
            # has been invoked
            obj = HackedObj(obj, gettypeid)

        return (obj, exposed, gettypeid)

class HackedServer(Server):
    def __init__(self, registry, address, authkey, serializer):
        super().__init__(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
        self.id_to_obj = HackedDict(self.id_to_obj)

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    _Server = HackedServer

class ProxyBase(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__')
class AProxy(ProxyBase): pass
class BProxy(ProxyBase): pass

MyManager.register('A', callable=A, proxytype=AProxy)
MyManager.register('B', callable=B, proxytype=BProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This process: ", os.getpid())
    with MyManager() as manager:
        myB = manager.B()
        print("Proxy process, using B directly: ", myB.pid)
        
        myA = manager.A()
        print('myA.b', myA.b)
        
        print("Proxy process, via A: ", myA.a.pid)
```

The key to the solution is to replace the `_Server` in our manager, and then wrap the `id_to_obj` dict with the one that performs the hack for the specific method we need.

The hack consists on populating the `gettypeid` dict for the method, but only after it  has been evaluated and we know the return type to be one that we would need a proxy for. And we're lucky in the order of evaluations, `gettypeid` is accessed after the method has been called.

Also luckily `gettypeid` is used as a local in the `serve_client` method, so we can return a copy of it and modify it and we don't introduce any concurrency issues.

While this was a fun exercise, I have to say I really advise against this solution, if you're dealing with external code that you cannot modify, you should simply create your own wrapper class that has explicit methods instead of `@property` accessors, proxy your own class instead, and use `method_to_typeid`.